# SUG BR Meeting in June 7

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Date/Time (EST): Wednesday, June 7, 2017, 6:30 PM EST

Date/Time (EST): Wednesday, June 7, 2017, 21:30 PM UTC

Location: Iguaçu street, 73, Florianópolis - Brazil

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/SUG-BR/events/240193761/

Twitter: #SUGBR

It will be broadcasted live. More details shortly

AGENDA

18:30 - 19:00 (21:30 - 22:00 UTC) - Networking and snacks (local only - sorry :P)

19:00 - 19:45 (22:00 - 22:45 UTC) - Sitecore + Azure better together with Vinicius Deschamps

19:45 - 20:00 (22:45 - 23:00 UTC) - Q&A

20:10 - 20:55 (23:10 - 23:55 UTC) - Hands on Helix - Building a component from scratch with Rodrigo Peplau

20:55 - 21:10 (23:55 - 00:10 UTC) - Q&A

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 3 days

Comment: thanks @MarkCassidy